# How to Create one-to-one relationship by non-primary key (EF First Code)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I have two classes 'Car' and 'CarDetails'

```
 
    public class Car {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Guid CarGuid { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual CarDetails CarDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarDetails {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Guid CarGuid { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }

        public int Weight { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CarGuid")]
        public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I want to create a relationship between two classes by 'CarGuid', but EF won't allow me to do so, Please help me!

Comment: In order to have a one-to-one relationship with EF, both tables must share the same primary key. This means that `CarDetails` should have the same primary key as `Car`, and `CarDetails` should have a FK for its primary key column.

Comment: Thanks. Can you write the correct code? (Of course it can be done in a database.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a one-to-one (or one-to-zero or one) relationship between two EF entities / SQL tables using a non-primary-key property / column. You have to use primary key columns to achieve this kind of relationship with EF.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CarGuid { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CarDetails CarDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CarDetails
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CarGuid { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

With the above relationship, you end up having `Car` as the principal, and `CarDetails` as the dependent. By having `CarDetails.Id` be both the primary key of `CarDetails` and the foreign key referencing `Car.Id`, you can ensure that each `Car` has no more than 1 `CarDetails`.

However, this is technically not a `1<->1` relationship... it is a `1<->0..1` relationship. This type of model will allow `Car` objects to exist without any corresponding `CarDetils` objects.

If you want something closer to a `1<->1` relationship, I believe the only way to do that is with the fluent model builder:

```
public class CarsDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<CarDetails>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Car).WithRequiredDependent(x => x.CarDetails)
        ;

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

With the above definition, you cannot save a `Car` unless you also save a corresponding `CarDetails` within the same SaveChanges operation. This is as close to a `1<->1` as entityframework will take you. You can achieve the same thing from the other side of the relationship in a similar way:

```
public class CarsDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.CarDetails).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Car)
        ;
        modelBuilder.Entity<CarDetails>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I want to create a relationship between two classes by 'CarGuid', but EF won't allow me to do so

Comment: You cannot have a 1 to 1 relationship using `CarGuid` unless `CarGuid` is the primary key of both classes (tables). It is not possible with EF.